# how to delete data where idin database with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want delete any image in database with id_product I call, but the result just one image, not all image where id_product.

my database :

```html
+------------------------------+
|id_image | id_product | image | 
+------------------------------+
|   1     |   22     | ab.jpg  |
|   2     |   22     | ak.jpg  |
+------------------------------+
```

my controller :

```
function produk_dihapus(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $name = $this->input->get('name');
    $this->produk_adm->hapus_any_image($id);
    log_helper("produk", "Menghapus produk ".$name."");
}
```

my model :

```
function hapus_any_image($id){
    $result = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('produk_image',array('id_produk'=>$id));
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) 
    {
        //print_r($result);
        unlink('assets/img/produk/'.$result['gambar']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`$this->db->get_where()`** in the place of **`$this->db->get()`** for matching with where condition.So in **model**

**Replace**

```
$query = $this->db->get('produk_image',array('id_produk'=>$id));
```

**With**

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('produk_image',array('id_produk'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like you passed parameter you can simple apply the `where` condition or `get_where` like this

```
$this->db->where('id_produk',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('produk_image');
$data = $query->result_array();
foreach ($data as $result) 
{
    unlink('assets/img/produk/'.$result['gambar']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code as its valid in all versions of codeigniter.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produk_image WHERE id_product = ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array(22));  /* product id = 22 in array*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->where_in('id_produk', $ids);
$query = $this->db->get('produk_image');
```